# Android Max View Count?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-lint

I'm writing an app with 100+ (116 to be precise) Image Buttons. When I'm trying to run the app, it automatically closes and tells me the following:

> The maximum view count defaults to 80 but can be configured with the environment variable ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT.

I need all of these Buttons, removing some of them isn't possible. What can I do? It says its bad for performance, but is it really that bad? Since its "just" a warning. Where can I configurate that environment variable? Or should I rather try to somehow lower the amount of buttons? (If yes, could you tell me how I can do that?)

Answer (score 4):

First of all why do you have so  many buttons? You might be able to achieve what you want using other UI components such as a `ListView`.

Anyways, it is a [Lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html) warning:

> The Android lint tool is a static code analysis tool that checks your
>   Android project source files for potential bugs and optimization
>   improvements for correctness, security, performance, usability,
>   accessibility, and internationalization.

**In Eclipse** Lint warnings can be configured from:

> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking.

[image]

Comment: ListView helps organizing it, but still, after about 80 entrys the app crashes.

Comment: In Android studio file->Settings->Code Style->Inspections. If you wish you can disable the warning "Layout has too many views"

Comment: If you cannot compile, in the terminal write: set ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT=100   (set the value according to the number of views you have)